# Issues with shell_exec in php

Tags: php, html, powershell

I have a HTML form with some PHP to execute a PowerShell script.

All works fine, except for the textarea input field. If I do a single line of text in the textarea box, it works OK and launches the PowerShell script. If I insert multiples lines of text, including carriage returns, it only will take the first word/line and cut the rest.

Here is the command that launches the PowerShell script:

with one word in the textarea box:

```
 powershell -command file.ps1 -textarea 'test'
```

with multiple words in the box

```
powershell -command file.ps1 -textarea 'firstword
```

As shown above, when multiple lines are in the TextArea field, it will strip it and only send the first word. This causes the PowerShell script to fail as the terminator is missing.

Any ideas?

Here is the code:

```
if($isValid) {
$customerid     = $_POST["DLState"];
$changesubject  = $_POST['subject'];
$starttime      = $_POST['starttime'];
$endtime        = $_POST['endtime'];
$changedetails  = $_POST['details'];
$psScriptPath   = "*****";

$query = shell_exec("powershell -command $psScriptPath -username '$user' -subject '$changesubject' -orgid '$customerid' -textarea '$changedetails' -edt '$endtime' -sdt '$starttime' < NUL");
  }
```

HTML text area tag

```
<textarea id="txtarea" name="details" cols="40" rows="6"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your script and all those username/subject/orgid/etc are script properties for $psScriptPath then you could try to run it this way:

```
  $query = shell_exec("powershell -command &quot;& {$psScriptPath -username '$user' -subject '$changesubject' -orgid '$customerid' -textarea '$changedetails' -edt '$endtime' -sdt '$starttime'}&quot;");
```

At least this works for me quite well:

Test Script:

```
PS C:\> gc c:\1.ps1
param($App)
& $App
```

Invoking from CMD shell:

```
C:\powershell -noprofile -command "& {c:\1.ps1 -App 'Notepad.exe'}"
```

Comment: When changing my line to your above format, I receive the following PHP error:

Comment: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '{' in C:\index.php on line 73

Comment: Yeah, I think we're missing some of double quotes - """

Comment: I have edited my code a bit, replaced " to - &quot; so it would get executed via php propery, i think

Answer (score 0):

Seemed like the windows shell didn't like the carriage return/line feed, so I base64 encoded the string, and then decoded it once it got into PowerShell. All OK now.

```
$changedetails  = $_POST['details'];
$changedetailsencoded = base64_encode($changedetails);
```